# Stop git from merging branch_a into current when pulling remote/branch_a into branch_a

Tags: git

I am writing a script to update all of our repositories to the latest code on our main develop branch. It's basically:

`git -C ./$project pull origin develop:develop`

I cannot be sure that the person running the script isn't actively working on a feature branch, nor can I guarantee that the branch they are on is branched from develop. Therefore I wish to ONLY pull origin/develop into develop and nothing else. No more actions.

Currently when doing this, git pulls develop into develop and then tries to merge develop into the current branch. I don't want this last step. I scoured the docs for pull and fetch and didn't find anything that could help. Is there a way to do this without having to manually check if theres changes, stash, pop, etc.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "fetch" instead of pull

Comment: If I fetch, would that not leave the local branch still not up to date?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to checkout develop to merge into it. Commit/stash your work on the current branch first.

Comment: Yes you are right, I misunderstood the question a bit. So you want to merge remote without checking out it's local branch.?

Comment: In this case probaly a fetch and then a merge would do, but otherwise I'm not sure how to do it without checking out your local branch where you want to merge. Probably this could help https://intellipaat.com/community/13729/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts

Comment: That's currently what i've got, `git pull origin develop:develop` and that does in fact pull develop into develop while i'm on `feature/something`. However, git THEN tries to merge `develop` into `feature/something` and I'm not sure why or how to get it to stop.

Comment: I guess git needs to do this if your ```feature/something``` is branched from develop, otherwise it would lead to conflicts. I'm not sure what you want to achieve is possible in this case without checking out ```develop``` and stashing ```feature\something```.
Maybe you need to adjust your current branching strategy so ```feature\something``` is not a direct descendent of ```develop```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Don't do this at all.  Have people use `origin/develop` directly.  Teach them how and why.  All they need to do then is use `git fetch`.

Failing that, use `git fetch origin develop:develop` and be prepared for some people to have a problem.

## Long

`git pull` literally means:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command.

You can choose whether the second command is `git merge` or `git rebase` but either way you'll affect the current branch based on what you `git fetch`-ed in step 1.

Based on [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702435/stop-git-from-merging-branch-a-into-current-when-pulling-remote-branch-a-into-br#comment128419811_72702435):

> ... what i've got, `git pull origin develop:develop` and that does in fact pull develop into develop while i'm on `feature/something`. However, git THEN tries to merge develop into `feature/something` ...

Technically, `git pull origin develop:develop` *does not* `pull` their (origin's) `develop` into your (local) `develop`, because `pull` means `fetch + second command`.  All it does is *fetch* their `develop` into your `develop`—and that gives you an answer:

```
git fetch origin develop:develop
```

Remember that most<sup>1</sup> `git pull` arguments are passed directly to `git fetch`.  It's that first command that is doing all the work here!  So just invoke it.  But there are some issues here, so read on.

---

<sup>1</sup>The exceptions here are:

- options that are specific to the *second* command, and
- options that are "eaten" by `git pull` itself, such as the one to specify which second command to use.

---

#### What could go wrong?

The `git fetch` command means:

- Call up some other Git repository (in this case `origin`), using the URL stored under a *remote:* a short name for some other Git repository.  A remote, like `origin`, is just a name under which Git can store some information:

  - a URL for fetch and/or push (you can have a different push URL);
  - some defaults and/or magic for fetch and/or push;
  - other (unspecified: Git reserves the right to add new stuff in the future).
- Have them list out their branch and tag names and the commits that go with these;
- download new commits if / as needed / desired; and
- based on the earlier steps, update any *remote-tracking names* (`origin/*` names in this case) as directed by some of the magic settings stored in under the remote's name.

To do this, `git fetch` needs the *name of a remote*, like `origin`.  You can run it with one:

```
git fetch origin
```

or without:

```
git fetch
```

If you run it without one, Git will guess *which* remote to use.  If you have only one remote—which is the typical case; most repositories just have one remote named `origin`—that's the one Git will guess and therefore use, so you can run `git fetch` with no arguments at all.

Having added a remote name, however, as in `git fetch origin`, you can then go on to list *branch* names as they're seen in the remote:

```
git fetch origin develop
```

for instance.  When you do this, you're telling your Git software that, although their Git may list out a dozen, or a million, branch names, you're only interested in updating *one*, namely `develop`.  That is, you want *your* `origin/develop` updated, based on *their* `develop`, and you're willing to skip updating all other `origin/*` names.<sup>2</sup>  Or you could run:

```
git fetch origin br1 br2 br7
```

and thereby update your `origin/br1`, your `origin/br2`, and your `origin/br7`.

Each of these *additional* arguments—which *absolutely require* the `origin` in front because they have to come *after* a remote; the first argument will be assumed to be a remote: `git fetch br1 develop` means "fetch `develop` from remote `br1`" whether or not `br1` is a branch name—is what `git fetch` calls a *refspec*.  It's a very simple kind of refspec, because a full refspec is made up of four parts:

- an optional leading plus sign `+`;
- a left hand name, such as `develop`;
- a right hand name, such as `develop`; and
- a separator colon (`:`) character that splits the left and right sides.

You get to *omit* the separator when you're writing just a left-side name, hence `git fetch origin develop` works fine.  If you're going to provide a *right*-side name, though, you must include the colon.

When we do use the colon here, that tells `git fetch` that it should attempt to create or update one of *our* names, in *our* repository.  This may fail.  In particular it *will* fail if `develop` is the *current* branch, and in several other cases.  Hence:

```
git fetch origin develop
```

will work,<sup>3</sup> but:

```
git fetch origin develop:develop
```

might fail.  So we need to handle the failure cases, or find an even-better way to deal with this.

There's another problem that occurs when `develop` is the current branch in any *added* working tree from `git worktree add`, and many versions of Git (from the point `git worktree add` was added in Git 2.5 until Git 2.35 was released) fail to detect this.  We'll touch on this later, but let's look at the issues with updating the local branch name `develop` in the normal (main) working tree first.

---

<sup>2</sup>The usual reason to do this here is to make *this* `git fetch` go faster.  This will probably make the *next* `git fetch` that fetches *everything*—the default—slower, since that one now has more to fetch.  So it's a "pay me now or pay me later" situation, and, as it turns out, paying now is often actually *cheaper* than paying later, as the total cost is often lower (reduced overhead plus, sometimes, better compression).  But not always—and "when to pay" is something you get to decide for yourself.

<sup>3</sup>If your network is down, or there's no `develop` *on* `origin`, `git fetch origin` can fail too.  But in these two cases we can't get anything at all done here, so we don't have to worry about them.

---

#### References and fast-forwards

A branch like `develop` name is a form of *reference* or *ref* in Git.  So is a remote-tracking name like `origin/develop`, and in fact, so are tags like `v1.2` and pretty much all other names, including `HEAD` (though `HEAD` is also called a *pseudoreference* because it has special magical properties in Git<sup>4</sup>).  This term, *ref*, is the reason that the `git fetch` arguments past the "remote" are called *refspecs:* they specify references, on both "sides" of a repository/repository interaction like `fetch` or `push`.

In any case, each branch or remote-tracking name in Git is constrained: it holds exactly one *commit* hash ID.<sup>5</sup>  Commits, in Git, have a special property: they *point backwards* to earlier commits.  This forms a [Drected Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) or DAG, and a DAG creates a partial order between commits, so that given any pair of commits <C<sub>1</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>> we can test whether C<sub>1</sub> ≺ C<sub>2</sub>.  The funny curly less-than `≺` character means *precedes* (and there's also equality and a successor property ≻ so we have a full set of ≼ etc operations—but the fact that this is a *partial* order means that C<sub>1</sub> ⊀ C<sub>2</sub> *does not imply* that C<sub>1</sub> ≽ C<sub>2</sub>: they may simply not have any defined order at all).

OK, so there's some math (*I was promised there would be no math!* [no you weren't](https://xkcd.com/1597/)), but we don't need to get into the details here: what it really *means* is that sometimes a branch "moves forward" in a nice neat simple way, and sometimes it doesn't.  Here's a simple illustration:

```
...--G--H   <-- alice
         \
          I--J   <-- bob
              \
               K--L   <-- carol
```

Here, Bob added two commits past what Alice did, and then Carol added two more commits past that.  (Newer commits are towards the right, older commits towards the left.)  We can move forward from where Alice is, to where Bob is, to where Carol is.

On the other hand, we can have this:

```
          I--J   <-- bob
         /
...--G--H   <-- alice
         \
          K--L   <-- carol
```

Here, if we're Alice, we can move forward two hops towards Bob and end up at commit `J`, or we can move forward two hops towards Carol and end up at `L`.  But once we've picked one of the two forward moves, we can't go *forwards* again to get to the other commits.  We would have to *back up* to get to them.

When we have this second situation, what we often do in Git is use `git merge` to *combine work*.  When we do that, Git produces this as our graph:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

I've taken away the *labels* (the branch names) and left only the *commits*.  The commits are what Git cares about, but the labels—the branch names—are how we have Git *find* the commits *for us*, so the labels also matter.  They do not matter much to Git, but they matter a lot to us.

What happens with Git repositories is that, if we're working on `develop` ourselves, we may make a commit or two that isn't over on `origin` yet:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

We're now using—working with—commit `J`.  Meanwhile someone else might `git push` their two commits to `develop` over on origin, and once we run `git fetch origin` we get:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/develop
```

We're now in the Bob-and-Carol situation I drew above: we have to go back in order to go forward, so what we'll usually do is run `git merge`.

**Git's `git fetch` does not run `git merge`, but Git's `git pull` does.**  That's the heart of the difference—or at least the original heart, before `pull` got all complicated-up with a rebase option—between fetch and pull.  And this really matters here, because *sometimes* `git merge` has a much easier situation.  Suppose we're on `develop`, but *we have not made any new commits of our own* so that we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

We then run `git fetch` which obtains new commits (I'll call them `K-L` again, skipping over `I-J`; commits' actual "names" are big ugly random-looking hash IDs, we're just using letters to keep things simple for our feeble human brains):

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/develop
```

If we now run `git merge` and give it the right stuff so that it merges commit `L`—e.g., `git merge origin/develop` or `git merge hash-of-L`—Git notices that this particular merge is trivial.  We literally haven't done any work that Git would need to combine, so Git can do a *fast-forward* instead of doing hard work, producing this:

```
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

This *fast forward* operation that `git merge` does *instead of merging* occurs when the *merge base* of the current commit and the target commit is the current commit.  Git calls this a *fast-forward merge* because we end up with commit `L` checked out in our working tree, along with having the name `develop` moved forwards like this.

Now, `git fetch` *can* do a very similar fast-forward operation with any of the *names* it wants to update.  Normally we have `git fetch` update our *remote-tracking names*, and it's very typical for those names to move in a fast-forward fashion.  (Technically this means that the "before" commit, that the remote-tracking name finds before `git fetch`, precedes the "after" commit.  Internally Git has that whole C<sub>1</sub> ≼ C<sub>2</sub> testing mechanism to decide if fast-forwarding is possible.)

---

<sup>4</sup>In particular, `.git/HEAD` is (currently at least) always a file, and if the file ever gets wrecked for some reason, Git will stop believing that the repository is a repository.  This can happen if your computer crashes while you're updating a branch.  Fortunately some of these cases are easy to recover from—but that's a topic for another question.

<sup>5</sup>Each ref holds exactly one hash ID, but some refs, such as tag names, can hold non-commit hash IDs.  Since remote-tracking names are made by copying the hash ID from some other Git's *branch* name, and a branch name is constrained to hold a commit hash ID, the remote-tracking name is similarly constrained.

---

#### The non-fast-forward case

Sometimes fast-forwarding is *not* possible.  For instance, if someone uses `git rebase` on a branch, and you use `git fetch` to update get their new commits, you will see, e.g.:

```
 + 6013c4a515...94929fa71c seen       -> origin/seen  (forced update)
```

The actual `git fetch` output here was:

```
[messages about enumerating and counting and compressing, snipped]
From <url>
   9c897eef06..ddbc07872e  master     -> origin/master
   9c897eef06..ddbc07872e  main       -> origin/main
   e54793a95a..dc8c8deaa6  maint      -> origin/maint
   c6f46106ab..0703251124  next       -> origin/next
 + 6013c4a515...94929fa71c seen       -> origin/seen  (forced update)
   7c89ac0feb..4d351f5272  todo       -> origin/todo
 * [new tag]               v2.37.0-rc0 -> v2.37.0-rc0
 * [new tag]               v2.37.0-rc1 -> v2.37.0-rc1
```

Note how *most* of the branch updates just print two commit hash IDs separated by two dots.  For instance, `main` goes from `9c897eef06` to `ddbc07872e`.  This means that `9c897eef06` is an *ancestor of* `ddbc07872e`.  But on `seen` (my `origin/seen`), some commit(s) have been *removed* and replaced with new-and-improved ones.  So that particular `git fetch` output line:

- is prefixed with `+`;
- contains three dots instead of two; and
- has `(forced updated)` appended.

All three of these tell us the same thing: that this was *not* a fast-forward operation.  Git tells us three times, because it is so important to know this.  (And yet many people never pay any attention here. )  A non-fast-forward update requires a certain extra added force, because it specifically "loses" commits off the end of a branch.  That is, we *had:*

```
          I--J   <-- origin/seen
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- where the `git fetch` is told to make `origin/seen` go
```

After forcing the update, we have:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/seen
```

Commits `I` and `J` still exist *in our repository* (and using the hash ID on the left side of the three dots above, I can find the old ones), but the *name* `origin/seen` will no longer find those.  It will find `L`, which finds `K`, which finds `H`, and so on, but it won't find `J` or `I` any more.

What makes `git fetch` *do* this "forced update" is that the *refspec* that has `git fetch` update the remote-tracking name has the leading plus sign `+` in it.  That leading plus sign is the "force flag".  It indicates that if a fast-forward operation is *not* possible, Git should go ahead and "lose commits" by doing a non-fast-forward forced update.

#### How `HEAD`, Git's index, and your working tree coordinate

When working in Git, you start with a repository.  At its heart, this is a pair of databases, with one (usually much bigger) holding commits and other Git internal objects, and one (usually much smaller) holding names ("refs" or "references").  The refs translate from human-readable names to hash IDs.  Git *needs* the hash IDs to look up objects in the bigger database.  Git does not *need* the names (in any technical sense), but humans do; because of this, Git provides the names and uses them in the ways it uses them.

The stuff in the bigger objects database is *all read-only*.  You can change the hash ID stored in any name, but you cannot change the *object* given by the hash ID.  If you make a bad commit (we all do now and then) you can make a new-and-improved *replacement* for it, and because new commits *add on*, it's easy to eject the *last* commit off the end of a just-added-to chain of commits and put in its place the *new* last commit.  That's how `git commit --amend` really works: the old commit didn't change, it just got ejected entirely, and as long as nobody notices the raw hash IDs, and just uses the branch names, nobody knows you made the bad commit in the first place.

But, because everything *in* every commit is completely read-only, we have a problem.  Technically each commit stores a full snapshot of *every* file, but in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format, that only Git can read.  That's great for archival and, well, utterly useless for getting any actual *work* done.

So besides the repository proper, Git gives us a *working tree*,<sup>6</sup> or *work-tree* for short.  The work-tree is simply *where you do your work*.  You pick some commit—by its hash ID, even if you use a branch name to have Git look up the hash ID for you—and tell Git: *I want to work with / on this commit.*  Git will *extract the files from that commit* and put them into your work-tree.

What you now have, in your work-tree, are ordinary everyday files.  All the programs on your computer can read and write *these* files.  They're not weird, Git-ified, de-duplicated things that might not even be files at all.<sup>7</sup>  They *are files*.  There's just one big hitch: *They are not in Git.*  Your working tree files may have come *out* of Git, but once out, they're just files, and not Git files at all.

Eventually, of course, you may want to take some work you've done with these ordinary files, and use those files to make a *new* commit.  If Git were like most other version control systems, you'd just tell Git to make a new commit and it would *automatically examine every working tree file*.  This is, or can be, pretty slow and painful.<sup>8</sup>  So that's not what Git does.

Instead, Git keeps a *third* copy—or "copy"—of every "active" file.  Most version control systems have two: there's one, read-only, in the *current commit*, and one more, that you're working on / with, in your working tree.  In Git, there's a third one that's sort of "in between" the other two.  That third Git "copy" is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.

I put "copy" in quotes like this because what's in Git's index is in the compressed-and-de-duplicated *format*.  It's not frozen the way a committed file is: in particular, you're allowed to *replace it wholesale*.  When you run `git add` on a file in your working tree, Git will:

- read the working tree copy;
- compress it and look to see if there's a duplicate;
- if it's a duplicate, use the original, tossing out the compressed result; if not, the compressed file is ready to be committed now.

So after `git add`, Git has the file ready to be committed.  Before `git add`, Git ... has the file ready to be committed, *in the form it has in the current commit*.  The de-duplication takes care of the fact that it's the same.  If you change a file *back* to the way it used to be and `git add` it, the de-duplication happens at `git add` time.  If you change it to something that's all-new, it's not a duplicate, and now there's an actual copy.  So what's in the index is *always ready to be committed* and is *pre-de-duplicated*.  This is what makes `git commit` so fast: it doesn't have to prepare a whole new commit after all.  All of the *files* that are to go *into* this commit are already pre-packaged; they just need a quick freeze operation to go into the new commit.

So, the *current commit*, Git's *index / staging-area*, and your *working tree* all coördinate.  Git knows the hash ID of the current commit.  Git has files in its index, always ready to be committed.  And for you, you have your working tree where you do your work.

If you decide *not* to work on the *current* commit, but rather to switch to some other branch and some other commit, you run:

```
git checkout otherbranch
```

or `git switch otherbranch` (since Git 2.23).  Git removes, from its index and your working tree, the *current* commit's files.  It installs, into its index and your working tree, the *other* commit's files.  Through its file de-duplication trick, Git can very quickly tell which of the files that have to be removed-and-replaced are literally exactly the same, and for those files, it can *skip all the work*, and make `git checkout` really fast.

There's one big caveat here.  The special file `HEAD`—the pseudo-ref we mentioned early on above—doesn't contain the *current commit hash ID*, at least not when we're "on" a branch.  Instead, it contains the *current branch name*.  That is, if we're on branch `develop`, the file `HEAD` just says "branch develop".  It's the *branch name itself* that contains the commit hash ID.  That commit hash ID leads to the archived snapshot that's in Git's index and your working tree and that's how Git knows which files to remove-and-replace if you switch to another commit.

Here's the problem: **If `HEAD` contains a branch name, we can't update that branch name.**  That's because the *name* holds the hash ID, and we need that hash ID later.

There's another mode in Git called *detached HEAD* mode.  Here, `HEAD` literally contains a raw hash ID, *instead of* a branch name.  In this mode it's safe to update any branch name, because `HEAD` has no branch name in it.  But we can still get the `git worktree add` problem: each added working tree necessarily includes its own `HEAD` and index (there's one `HEAD` and index per working tree, in other words).

So, whether or not we're "on" some branch in the *main* working tree, any *added* working trees have to be checked as well.  Git versions 2.5 through (but not including) 2.35 fail to do this check, so if you're going to be sneaky, and someone may have this Git version, you should do this check yourself.

---

<sup>6</sup>A so-called *bare* repository lacks the working tree.  This means nothing is ever checked out in the working tree (since there isn't one).

<sup>7</sup>Git's *blob objects* store the contents of the file; the names are stored weirdly; and a whole mess of objects can be scrunched together into what Git calls a *pack file*.  When using a pack file, you might have just one OS-style file (the pack file) that holds *all* the source files!  Git has other formats though, so that it can work efficiently; all of this is well-hidden, unlike the fact that there's an index and a working tree.

<sup>8</sup>Ask anyone who, back in the 1980s or 1990s or even later, would run the equivalent-of-commit verb in their system and then go out to lunch because it would be at least 15 minutes before anything else could happen.  Seriously, sometimes it was only one or two minutes, but it just felt really horrible and slow, and made people reluctant to commit.  When `git checkout` and `git commit` took only seconds, we all thought it must be broken.

The computers are way faster now, and with SSDs instead of 3600 RPM spinning media, the storage is much faster too, but now the projects are generally bigger, so it kind of evens out.

---

#### This gives us our list of failure cases

We *can* run `git fetch origin develop:develop`.  This has our Git software call up some other Git software, at whatever URL is stored under the name `origin`, and negotiate with that software to see if they have a branch named `develop`.  If so, our Git:

- obtains from their Git any new commits they have, that we don't, that we'll need to update our `origin/develop`;
- updates our `origin/develop` accordingly, with a forced update if necessary; and
- tries to update our `develop` with a *non*-forced update.

The update will fail if:

- the current branch is named `develop`: that's the current-commit-gets-desynchronized problem described above; or
- any added working tree is on branch `develop`, and the Git version is 2.35 or later: it won't fail in 2.5 and later up through but not including 2.35, but that's actually *worse* as such an added working tree is now desynchronized; or
- the update is not a fast-forward.

If nobody is using `git worktree add`, the middle problem—which is by far the worst—can't occur, so only the two problems that Git *will* notice and reject can occur.  But they can in fact occur.  If they do, it means the user should commit their work and merge-or-rebase as appropriate anyway (i.e., the user should be using `git pull` or equivalent here in the first place).  If someone *is* using `git worktree add` and has an added working tree that is "on" branch `develop`, they should use the git-pull-or-equivalent process in that particular added working tree.

#### Why users should use `origin/develop` directly

Suppose we're working on some feature branch that is to be added to some other repository's `develop` at some point, and we're supposed to rebase our feature branch as needed, or merge from the other repository's develop into our feature branch.  These are the normal everyday Git usages for which we occasionally need to update our `origin/develop`.

But we can update `origin/develop` trivially, *at any time*, by running `git fetch`.  This may do nothing, or fast-forward our `origin/develop`, or force-update our `origin/develop`.  **Whichever of these it does, our `origin/develop` is now up to date.**  We don't need a local `develop` branch at all!  We just now run:

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

or:

```
git merge origin/develop
```

as necessary and appropriate.

This same method-of-working applies to `main`: we don't need a `main` or `master` branch at all.  We can just work on our own branches, and use `origin/main` or `origin/master` directly.

If we have reason to look at the commit specified *by* `origin/main` or `origin/develop` or whatever, we can run:

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

and we'll be in "detached HEAD" mode, using the desired commit.  We then:

```
git checkout feature/ours
```

to get back to work on our feature.  Or, if we like `git switch`—it *is* more user-friendly and safer than `git checkout` was—we will run:

```
git switch --detach origin/develop
```

The `git switch` command *demands* the `--detach` flag, since Git newbies often don't understand what "detached HEAD" mode is about.  Detached HEAD mode isn't *difficult*, really, it's just a wrinkle that should be addressed when you need to.

Comment: Every day is a school day it seems. Thanks for the insanely detailed explanation. I'll heed your warning and have altered our update script to just run git pull if that repository is currently on develop otherwise do nothing. Hopefully that's a little safer.